# Why do more phase shifts cause the need for higher bandwidth when Frequency Shift Keying (FSK) is used?

Tags: frequency, modulation

What I don't get is why a phase shift "decreases" the data rate and thus the need for more bandwidth to get the same throughput as without the phase shift.

Comment: Can you ask the question with more detail. I don't understand "more phase shifts". I don't understand how a phase shift can decrease data rate either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you mean a discontinuous phase when switching between two symbols. If the phase jumps at the border between two symbols, your modulated signal is discontinuous. This means that it contains many (theoretically all) frequencies, so it has a large bandwidth. On the other hand, if you always have a continuous phase, there are no discontinuities in the modulated signal, which requires much less bandwidth. Note that the smoother a time-domain signal is, the smaller is its high-frequency content. FSK with a continuous phase is called (what else?) *continuous phase FSK* (CPFSK). It is a special case of *continuous phase modulation* (CPM). Also check [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_phase_modulation#Continuous-phase_frequency-shift_keying).

Comment: "I believe you mean a discontinuous phase when switching between two symbols." this is what I meant! But sure enough what you said:"This means that it contains many (theoretically all) frequencies, so it has a large bandwidth." is exactly what I don't understand.

Comment: @DatProgram: I tried to make it clear in one of the following sentences: "...the smoother a time-domain signal is, the smaller is its high-freq. content". And the opposite is also true, i.e. a signal with discontinuities has a lot of high frequencies, i.e. a large bandwidth.

Comment: Would it be worth noting that even if phase is continuous, an instantaneous frequency shift will *still* inject significant (probably unwanted) higher-frequency content, and so constraining signal bandwidth requires either limiting the rate at which the frequency shifts, or using some other technique to "smooth out" the transition.